# Is expression evaluated differently in watch window to in the code execution

Tags: visual-studio, covariance, visual-studio-2022, watch-window

I have the following code which will check if a `List<int>` is compatible with type `IEnumerable<object>`. Covariance does not apply to value types, so this expression should evaluate to false.

```
public class WatchWindowTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void WhenRun_WillEvalueToFalseInCode_AndTrueInWatchWindow()
    {
        object listOfInts = new List<int>();

        var x = false;

        // This line evaluates to false - covariance does not apply to value types
        if(listOfInts is IEnumerable<object>)
        {
            // This line is never executed
            x = true;
        }

        Assert.False(x);
    }
}
```

In the code above, the code will not enter the if block, as expected. However, in the watch window, the same expression will evaluate to true. (See image.)

[image: Expression evaluates to true in watch window.]

Is there a reason for this, or is there a bug in Visual Studio? (I'm using Visual Studio 2022 17.0.4)